# AADSTS700016: Failed to obtain access token when authenticating to Azure with MSAL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to authenticate to Azure using MSAL, which I specified as follows:

```
 app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id=client_id,
        client_credential=client_secret,
        authority='https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantname
    )
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)
```

It fails because it cannot find the company's tenantname I have access to even though it's correctly specified.

`Error description was: AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '12341234123somethingtest-fje2434823412341234123somethingtest-4322134-213413212341234123somethingtest' was not found in the directory '213412312341234123somethingtest-1234-3241'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Exception: Failed to obtain access token`

I've tried tenantname and tenant ID from the AAD as well and always got the same error.
Is there any way to resolve this issue? (The code worked perfectly when I used it on my own Azure.)

Comment: Have you checked if the application specified by `client_id` is available in the tenant against which you're running the code?

Comment: @GauravMantri The service principal registered has the same (Directory) tenant_id as the AAD tenant_id so it should be available?

Comment: Attempt to grant administrator consent for the application:  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}`,Run the url in the browser and log in with the administrator account and consent.

Comment: I had an issue with my client_id (last char missing) and the adminconsent URL helped a lot with debugging. Kindergarten mistake. Many thanks for the help. Fixed.

Comment: Great! I will summarize our discussion in the answer so that it can help more people, you can mark it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error has been resolved. It is caused by lack of characters in your **client_id**. You only need to enter the correct **client_id**.

Encountered similar problems,  can run admin consent url debugging in the browser:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}`.